# Write DataFrame to mysql table using pySpark

Tags: python, mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am attempting to insert records into a `MySql` table. The table contains `id` and `name` as columns.

I am doing like below in a `pyspark` shell.

```
name = 'tester_1'
id = '103'  
import pandas as pd
l = [id,name]

df = pd.DataFrame([l])

df.write.format('jdbc').options(
      url='jdbc:mysql://localhost/database_name',
      driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',
      dbtable='DestinationTableName',
      user='your_user_name',
      password='your_password').mode('append').save()
```

I am getting the below attribute error

`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'write'`

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct method to insert records into a `MySql` table from `pySpark`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Use Spark DataFrame instead of pandas', as `.write` is available on Spark Dataframe only

So the final code could be

```
data =['103', 'tester_1']

df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF(['id', 'name'])

df.write.format('jdbc').options(
      url='jdbc:mysql://localhost/database_name',
      driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',
      dbtable='DestinationTableName',
      user='your_user_name',
      password='your_password').mode('append').save()
```

Comment: I am getting this below error `java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DefaultSource does not allow create table as select.`. Is there any other alternative to this.

Comment: does that table exists in datasource and try playing with `mode` also.

Comment: I am getting this below error java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DefaultSource does not allow create table as select.. Is there any other alternative to this.

Comment: @Karn_way: does the table exists in the target or creating one?

Comment: yes table does exists . I am using CDH image with mysql . I think its been fixed in spark 2.0 where in my image its 1.6

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716155/how-to-write-to-jdbc-source-with-sparkr-1-6-0

Answer (score 0):

Just to add @mrsrinivas answer's.

Make sure that you have jar location of sql connector available in your spark session. This code helps:

```
spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .config("spark.jars", "/Users/coder/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar")\
    .master("local[*]")\
    .appName("pivot and unpivot")\
    .getOrCreate()
```

otherwise it will throw an error.