# Sum a column in dataframe and return results as int

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with a column of numbers(amount). I need to sum that column(amount) and then have the result return as an int in a python variable.

Dataset looks like this:

```
date,p1id,p2id,amount,p3id
1/1/2013,U2_P1,p@c.com,100,P_P
```

With the date grouping and aggregation by sum.

```
groupby_revenue = df.groupby(['date']).sum()
print(groupby_revenue)
```

output:

```
DataFrame[visitdate: string]
```

original output:

```
1/1/2013    13000
1/1/2014    16090
1/1/2015    17330
```

Comment: Please share the output format of the data.

Comment: DataFrame[visitdate: string] this is the output iam getting

Comment: But need to get like this
1/1/2013    13000
1/1/2014    16090
1/1/2015    17330

Answer (score 1):

You need to collect it:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

groupby_revenue = df.groupby(['date']).agg(F.sum('amount')).collect()[0][0]
```

Comment: Getting the below error:
ValueError: No objects to concatenat

Answer (score 1):

When working with `spark` you need to understand its `execution process` and `programming api` (`pyspark - http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html`). It is totally different from `pandas/python` execution. Its execution depends on the `lazy evaluation`, whenever you need to check data you need to perform an action like `show`, `first`, `collect` or `take`. Without these actions, it returns on `dataframe` with `schema` (so in your question).

Let me introduce you to a few things with an example:-

```
process_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ['2013-01-01','U2_P1','p@c.com','100','P_P'],
    ['2013-01-01','U2_P2','p@c.com','100','P_P1'],
    ['2014-01-01','U2_P1','p@c.com','100','P_P'],
    ['2014-01-01','U2_P2','p@c.com','100','P_P1'],
    ['2015-01-01','U2_P1','p@c.com','100','P_P'],
    ['2015-01-01','U2_P2','p@c.com','100','P_P1']
], ['date','p1id','p2id','amount','p3id'])

#This prints Schema instead of Data
print process_df
DataFrame[date: string, p1id: string, p2id: string, amount: string, p3id: string]

#This prints data instead of schema
process_df.show()
+----------+-----+-------+------+----+
|      date| p1id|   p2id|amount|p3id|
+----------+-----+-------+------+----+
|2013-01-01|U2_P1|p@c.com|   100| P_P|
|2013-01-01|U2_P2|p@c.com|   100|P_P1|
|2014-01-01|U2_P1|p@c.com|   100| P_P|
|2014-01-01|U2_P2|p@c.com|   100|P_P1|
|2015-01-01|U2_P1|p@c.com|   100| P_P|
|2015-01-01|U2_P2|p@c.com|   100|P_P1|
+----------+-----+-------+------+----+

agg_data = process_df.groupby(['date']).agg({'amount':'sum'})

#This prints Schema instead of Data
print agg_data
DataFrame[date: string, sum(amount): double]

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

#This prints data instead of schema
agg_data.show()
+----------+-----------+
|      date|sum(amount)|
+----------+-----------+
|2015-01-01|      200.0|
|2014-01-01|      200.0|
|2013-01-01|      200.0|
+----------+-----------+

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
agg_data.select('date', F.col('sum(amount)').alias('sum')).show()
+----------+-----+
|      date|  sum|
+----------+-----+
|2015-01-01|200.0|
|2014-01-01|200.0|
|2013-01-01|200.0|
+----------+-----+
```

> This is an example to print only data if you need to take this data in
>   python then need to use collect, take, first, head. Here are a few
>   examples:-

```
print agg_data.collect()
[Row(date=u'2015-01-01', sum(amount)=200.0),
 Row(date=u'2014-01-01', sum(amount)=200.0),
 Row(date=u'2013-01-01', sum(amount)=200.0)]
print agg_data.first()
Row(date=u'2015-01-01', sum(amount)=200.0)
print agg_data.take(1)
[Row(date=u'2015-01-01', sum(amount)=200.0)]
agg_data.head()
Row(date=u'2015-01-01', sum(amount)=200.0)
```

> This is how we can take data to python and can wrangle over it.

```
Hope this will help a lot.
```

Comment: How to store the output of this data into spark sql db?

Comment: @user10389226 I found this link for saving data into sql db https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552161/write-dataframe-to-mysql-table-using-pyspark, Basically, you need connection string and options.

Comment: How to install jdbc driver in windows?
while executing its shows sc not define(How to import sqlcontext)?